# Always round set seconds / minutes /hours to 00 mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, rounding

In my database I have the following date-times:

```
2019-12-12 01:56:46.825
2019-12-12 02:56:47.831
2019-12-12 02:56:47.831
```

I want to be able to retrieve these records with the hours, minutes or seconds set to their 00 values:

For example I want to be able to return records with seconds and milliseconds set to 00:

```
2019-12-12 01:56:00.000
2019-12-12 02:56:00.000
2019-12-12 02:56:00.000
```

Or return them setting the minutes to zero as well.

```
2019-12-12 01:00:00.000
2019-12-12 02:00:00.000
2019-12-12 02:00:00.000
```

How can I write a query to format my results as desired?

**I tried :**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
concat(
    date_format(data_log.time,'%Y-%m-%d '),
    TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(((TIME_TO_SEC(data_log.time) +30) DIV 60) * 60), '%H:%i:%s')) 
AS result
```

*This returns the result with seconds set to 00 so im getting closer*

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Extract the wanted fields, and create new date/time values.

Comment: I tried date_format, and time_format

Comment: So show us that code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know which parts of the time you want to get as zero then a simple

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2009-10-04 22:23:22.023', '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00.000');
```

will return

```
2009-10-23 22:00:00.000
```

Or

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2009-10-04 22:23:22.023', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00.000');
```

will return

```
2009-10-23 22:23:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `str_to_date()` works fine in this case:

```
str_to_date(datecol, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')
```

or

```
str_to_date(datecol, '%Y-%m-%d %H')
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/98qoDVfknzFeFp1s6u88Z9/2).